# I'm unable to call img path using single quotes in an array?

Tags: php, images, urls, array, comment-form

I would like to call an image next to input field in wp comment form. But I'm unable to do that. I call image when **''** <= single quotes doesn't exist. But I don't know how to call an image in single quotes. Can someone show me how please.

my fields in array

```
    <?php $comments_args = array(

        'comment_notes_before' => 
            '<p class="comment-notes">' . __( 'Your email address will not be published.', 'hemingway' ) . '</p>',

        'comment_field' => 
            '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" required>' . '</textarea></p>',

        'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

            'author' =>
                '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="' . __('Name','hemingway') . '" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" />' . '<label for="author">Author</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</p>',
            'code' =>
                '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/social/facebook-share.png" />',

                '<input id="code" name="image" type="text" placeholder="" value="" size="30" />',

            'email' =>
                '<p class="comment-form-email">' . '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="' . __('Email','hemingway') . '" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" /><label for="email">Email</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</p>',

            'url' =>
            '<p class="comment-form-url">' . '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="' . __('Website','hemingway') . '" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /><label for="url">Website</label></p>')
  ),
    );
```

I would like to show an image just after **'code' =>** but I'm getting error. do here quotes conflict or occur something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use PHP tags while inside a string:

```
'<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/social/facebook-share.png" />'
```

You need to instead use concatenation:

```
'<img src="' . esc_url( get_bloginfo('template_directory') ) . '/images/social/facebook-share.png" />'
```

Or my personal favorite, `sprintf()`:

```
sprintf(
    '<img src="%1$s/images/social/facebook-share.png" />',
    esc_url( get_bloginfo('template_directory') )
);
```